# Why am I having trouble creating a custom array method that returns a hash with indices of matching array values?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to monkey patch the Array class with a method that, when passed something like `[1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 1]`, will return a hash with `{ 1 => [0, 6], 3 => [1, 3, 5] }`, where the key is the number we are matching to, and the value is an array with the indices of all matches.

Here's the code I have so far. I can't tell why it's returning something like `{1=>[0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0], 3=>[0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0], 0=>[0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0]}`:

```
class Array

  def dups

    matches = {}
    matches_index = []

    self.each do |i|
      self[(i_index + 1)..-1].each_with_index do |j, j_index|
        matches_index << j_index if self[i] == self[j]
      end
      matches[i] = matches_index
    end

    matches.keep_if { |key, value| value.length > 1 }
  end

end
```

Comment: Why is the return value `{ 1 => [0, 6], 3 => [1, 3, 5] }` and not `{ 1 => [0, 6], 3 => [1, 3, 5] 4 => [2], 0 => [4] },`? You didn't explain that in the text.

Comment: For all posted answers that include singular items, you can remove those via  `dups.delete_if {|k,v| v.size == 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve on Stas S already excellent solution:

```
class Array
  def dups
    (self.each_index.group_by {|i| self[i]}).keep_if{|k, v| v.size > 1}
  end
end
```

Which results in an array of *only* duplicates.

Comment: Cool, didn't see your answer originally, but that's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 6):

This is an even shorter version:

```
class Array
  def dups
    each_index.group_by{|i| self[i]}.select{|k,v| v.size > 1}
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one, good job :)

Comment: Nice solution, one to remember.

Comment: Nice solution. But, you don't need the `self` at the beginning. Also, the OP seems to want to select those whose length of the value (array) is greater than one.

Comment: @sawa, thanks for your observation! Didn't notice this requirement at first. I updated my answer.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. Only thing I added was a line below to filter out anything that didn't have a match: matches.select { |k, v| v.length > 1}

Comment: @mss You didn't explain that in the text. Don't expect people to read your code throughout.

Comment: Ah, this is the way to do it.

Comment: @tokland, `'awesome extensions'` are already in the core ;)

Comment: @StasS touché. But I still kind of prefer `with_index.group_by_pair`, more declarative ;-) Still finding a better name for `group_by_pair` though...

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks very complicated (and very imperative). A functional approach is way easier:

```
class Array
  def dups
    grouped_indexed = each_with_index.group_by(&:first)
    Hash[grouped_indexed.map { |x, gs| [x, gs.map(&:last)] }]
  end
end
```

Is this still too complicated? well, yes, but that's because the core is missing some basic abstractions like [map_by](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/map_by.rb):

```
require 'facets'
xs = [1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 1]
xs.each_with_index.to_a.map_by { |x, i| [x, i] }
#= {1=>[0, 6], 3=>[1, 3, 5], 4=>[2], 0=>[4]}
```

To be honest, even that one-liners is too verbose. With the right abstractions we should be able to write something like this:

```
require 'awesome_functional_extensions'
xs = [1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 1]
xs.with_index.group_by_pair
#= {1=>[0, 6], 3=>[1, 3, 5], 4=>[2], 0=>[4]}
```

Comment: I knew you'd show up :)

Comment: When a functional approach is needed, here I am :-)

Comment: What does `xs` stand for?

Comment: @sawa: it's like `x`, but plural :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It is not assigned anywhere.

Comment: @sawa: ah, that. I bet it was just a copy/paste error. Seems that tokland meant to use `self` there, obviously.

Comment: This is a really cool way of doing it, any good articles/libraries (besides the one you linked to) related to functional programming in ruby?

Comment: I used `xs` to avoid repeating the monkeypatching, just show the code. But `xs` is initialized both times it's used. @mss: my wikipage on FP with Ruby: https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Comment: @tokland: it's used three times and first time it's not initialized. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array

  def dups
    matches = {}
    self.each_with_index do |v, i|
      matches.has_key?(v) ? matches[v] << i  : matches[v] = [i]
    end
    matches
  end

end

x = [1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 3, 1]
puts x.dups
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version:

```
class Array
  def dups
    to_enum
    .with_index
    .group_by(&:first)
    .select{|_, a| a.length > 1}
    .each_value{|a| a.map!(&:last)}
  end
end
```